# Microsoft azure project name grayed out

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobssdk

In Visual Studio 2013.3 when adding azure webjob the project name is grayed out.

When I click OK it says:

Unable to create a WebJob.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: project

[image: Azure project name]

Comment: Are there other projects in the solution?

Comment: Yes there is a web project which is also deployed on azure and this works OK.

Comment: Did you choose to 'Add Existing Project as Azure WebJob' or 'New Azure WebJob Project'?

Comment: No. I have these options only available on web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in the way the template is initially created if you go through Add > New Project instead of right click on a Website and clicking "Add New Webjob".

The window you're seeing is, in fact, not a publish window. It's a "Create Web Job Project" window. It's doing that because it's confused from this missing file I guess?

Anyway it's missing a webjob-publish-settings.json file under the Properties of the project.

Mine basically has this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "MyWebjob",
  "startTime": "2014-08-10T00:00:00-08:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Day",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

Edit: I added this file to my project and it still really wasn't enough. My recommendation is to go to your existing web site, right click, select "Add > New Azure WebJobs Project" and recreate the project that way. I'm not exactly certain what it's missing, but doing it any other way is apparently bugged.

Comment: Hej! I've created new "Web job project" and the problem is still there.

Comment: You right click on the Web Project, go to Add > New Azure WebJobs Project and you get that screen, and it's still grayed out?

Comment: I think I figured out. When I added Dummy Azure WebJob from WebProject it started to work from everywhere. Thnx.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do 2 things:

1) Add **webjob-publish-settings.json** into the **Properties** folder:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "[your-webjob-name]",
  "startTime": null,
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": null,
  "interval": null,
  "runMode": "Continuous"
}
```

2) Add [Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish/) NuGet package to your project. Note: you should run VS as administrator to install this package successfully.

Now you can easily publish your WebJob from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a console app with no relation to any website. For me it worked to.

1. Add the NuGet-package "Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish"
2. Get an webjob-publish-settings.json into the properties folder.

   ```
     {
     "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
     "webJobName": "WebJob1",
     "startTime": "2014-06-23T00:00:00-08:00",
     "endTime": "2014-06-27T00:00:00-08:00",
     "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
     "interval": 5,
     "runMode": "Scheduled"
   ```

   }
3. Then when i right clicked on my console-app i got a dialogbox similar to the one i get when i publish a website. Now i shall test if it works as well, but it published at least :)